# How to slice/clip an imported image and save it in oracle database if suppose given image of sombody's face?

Tags: java, c#, .net, oracle10g

I had imported an face image in my project and my program has many modules like show image, clip image,
In clipping i had sevral baby modules like Clip hairs,clip fore head ....etc.Each imported image associates an id with it. And each clipped part also has same id as of original one . I want when i click on several clip buttons, the part should be saved in database. Now how to clip image in various parts?